# Why does `%4.` add space to my number?

Tags: java, string, formatting, format, string-formatting

I have this code:

```
private String padWithZeroRightToPeriod(String serverFormat, float unformattedNumber, int index) {
    int nDigits = getNumberOfDigitsAfterPeriod(serverFormat);
    String floatingFormat = "%4." + nDigits + "f";
    String formattedPrice = String.format(floatingFormat, unformattedNumber);
```

When called with `unformattedNumber` being `846`, why is the result `" 846"` (a space and then the three digits)?

What does the `%4.` mean?

Comment: Did you look at the Javadocs?  Did you try any other inputs to understand the behaviour?

Comment: couldn't search it well in the java docs. what term to use? string formatter didn't help

Comment: What do you mean "didn't help"? [It's very well documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider it means that `%[argument_index$][flags][width]` is not clear to me. I can try a few examples but i want to understand the behavior and not guess it.

Comment: no, but his example did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs for `String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) refer you to [this documentation on format strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), which says:

> The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:
>
> `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`
>
> The optional *argument_index* is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by "1$", the second by "2$", etc.
>
> The optional *flags* is a set of characters that modify the output format. The set of valid flags depends on the conversion.
>
> The optional *width* is a positive decimal integer indicating the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.
>
> The optional *precision* is a non-negative decimal integer usually used to restrict the number of characters. The specific behavior depends on the conversion.
>
> The required *conversion* is a character indicating how the argument should be formatted. The set of valid conversions for a given argument depends on the argument's data type.

From your example output, it appears that `getNumberOfDigitsAfterPeriod` is returing `0`, so your format string is `%4.0f`. So:

- It doesn't have an *argument index* (there's no `$` after the `4`)
- It has a *width* (`4`)
- It has a *precision* (`0`)
- And of course it has a *conversion* (`f`)

So 846 is output as `" 846"` because the width is 4. The width in question is the *total* number of characters output. Here's a different example: [Live Copy](http://ideone.com/olkszE)

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%8.2f", 846.0));
        System.out.println(String.format("%8.2f", 42.4));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  846.00
   42.40
```

Note that each of those is eight characters long.

Comment: `It has a width (4)`. does 42.4 has a width of 4 ?

Comment: @user1065869: Yes, the width is the *"minimum number of characters to be written to the output"* (e.g., in total). But given your example output of `" 846"`), apparently `getNumberOfDigitsAfterPeriod` is returning `0`. `String.format("%4.0f", 42.4)` returns `"  42"` (two spaces followed by 42).